# Ap insight Not loggin although Developer mode enabled

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a block of code, where I have enabled the developer mode, but still the logs are not logging in the App insight.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {

                try
                {
                    int a = 5;
                    int b = 0;
                    int c = a / b;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    CreateLogAI(ex, "code");
                }

            }
        }

        public static void CreateLogAI(Exception ex, string CodeBlock)
        {
            TelemetryClient TeleClient = new TelemetryClient();
            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "XXXX";
            try
            {
                TeleClient.TrackException(ex);
                TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel.DeveloperMode = true;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                throw exception;
            }

            finally { TeleClient.Flush(); }
        }
```

So I referred number of article. Developer mode & the Flush should work. This is the sample code I have. What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Sleep after Flush(). `Thread.Sleep(5000);`

Answer (score 0):

I just copy your code, and it works fine and logs can be seen in azure portal.

There are two steps you can use to check if logs are sent to appInsights:

1.After run your code in visual studio, please check the output window, see if this line of text is there, it starts with `Application Insights Telemetry:`, screenshot as below:
[image]

2.If you cannot see the message describe in step 1, please add `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)` before the `Flush()` method in `finally{}`, then check the output window again.

Here is the test result at my side, please note that it may take a few minutes for the logs to be shown in azure portal:
[image]

Comment: Yes I can see the error in App insight now. But my concern is ultimately the code is working but its taking some time to reflect. AS suggested thread.sleep might work, but in live application we can't make the thread sleep for each logging

Comment: Actually, you don't need to add the sleep for each logging, you can add the sleep where the code exits. In this example, you can add it at the end of the Main() method.

Comment: do not sleep or flush after every call to the client to log telemetry, though.    if you have a "short running" app like a console app or something, make sure you flush+sleep before the process ends.  in a "real" app, you would normally be constantly collecting telemetry and the telemetry client is batching them and sending them in a way that will try not to mess with the perf of your application.  putting flush + sleep *everywhere* is not what you want.

Comment: "not immediate logging" means the logs does not appear in azure portal immediately? or others?

Comment: and if it works, could you please help mark it answer, it would be helpful for others :)